# Disabling oom killer affects the area allocated by kmalloc()?

Tags: c, linux, out-of-memory, powerpc, kmalloc

My Linux Kernel Version is 2.6.34.13
CPU is Powerpc.

I would like to make OOM-killer disabled completely in both user process and kernel module.

By configuring with fowllowing parameters, I disabled oom killer.

> vm.overcommit_memory = 2
>   vm.overcommit_ratio = 100

In this case, `malloc()` returns available address until all (physical memory + swap) areas are allocated. If all areas are already allocated, it will return NULL and OOM killer will not perform.

However, how about `kmalloc()` with GFP_KERNEL argument?
If ZONE_NORMAL areas are allocated completely, `kmalloc()` returns NULL? and OOM killer not perform?